# How to Lighten or Shade an Includegraphics Image

Tags: color, includegraphics, shading

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{transparent}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=20em,height=30em]{example-image}\llap{\texttransparent{0.5}{\color{blue!90}\rule{20em}{30em}}}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{-45pt}
\hskip 150pt\includegraphics[scale=4.5]{Blue_Image.png}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Notice the lower blue rectangle is slightly darker than the upper blue image.

I would like them to be the same; and it seems that I may accomplish this by slightly lightening (if possible), the lower `includegraphics` png image.

I am under the impression that I cannot change the color of an `includegraphics` image in Latex, but it seems reasonable that one might be able to simply lighten or darken it. Perhaps I am wrong.

QUESTION: Is there a way to lighten or darken a png image via the `includegraphics` command; and if so, how may one do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Bit ugly, but couldn't you do what you've done with example image but with transparent white rectangle?

Comment: @DavidPurton The problem is when I use an online snippit tool---the color does not always transform exactly. So, if I want to match such a cut-out to an includegraphics image in Latex, it would be useful to be able to lighten or shade the imported image.

Comment: Hmm. I confess I'm not 100% sure exactly what you mean. Do you just mean an interface question? i.e., something like `\includegraphics[lighten=0.5]{}` should lighten up each pixel by 50%? (which would be equivalent to putting a 50% transparent white rectangle over the top of the image or perhaps doing a screen blend with a grey rectangle.)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252256/87678

Comment: @DavidPurton Yes---`\includegraphics[lighten=0.5]{}` but `lighten=0.5` seems not to work for me.

Comment: @DavidPurton I saw the link you provided earlier, but wasn't sure if it applies here for it indicates "Beamer"

Comment: I just made up the `lighten` thing. It's not a feature

Comment: More promising: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150219/87678

Comment: @DavidPurton I've seen that one; because of Martin's Sharer's comment, ``No, \includegraphics can't change the image color.'' I indicated earlier that I am under the impression that color cannot be changed with `includegraphics`. But again, I am not trying to "change" the color---just lighten (or darken it) if possible.

Comment: What about Bruno's decodearray option? Did you try that?

Comment: @DavidPurton I don't know what that is.

Comment: In the most recent answer I linked to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think using the `decodearray` option to `\includegraphics` can suit your purposes. Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150219/87678).

For RGB images, `decodearray` takes 3 pairs of numbers between 0 and 1. The three pairs adjust the red, green and blue channels respectively. In your case you can make each of the three pairs the same since you just want to lighten (or darken) each image rather than actually change colours.

The pairs of numbers map channel levels (which run from 0 to 1) linearly on to the new scale you specify in the two numbers.

So to lighten by 50% you would use `decodearray={0.5 1 0.5 1 0.5 1}`. In other words, for each channel (0 … 1) → (0.5 … 1).

**Caveat:** This seems to work with `pdftex` and `xetex`, but not `luatex` ([bug?](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-luatex/2022-December/006716.html)).

### MWE

You need the image (`blue_square.png`):

[image: blue_square]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{blue_square}
\includegraphics[decodearray={0.2 1 0.2 1 0.2 1}]{blue_square}
\includegraphics[decodearray={0.4 1 0.4 1 0.4 1}]{blue_square}
\includegraphics[decodearray={0.6 1 0.6 1 0.6 1}]{blue_square}
\includegraphics[decodearray={0.8 1 0.8 1 0.8 1}]{blue_square}
\includegraphics[decodearray={1 1 1 1 1 1}]{blue_square}

\bigskip

\includegraphics{blue_square}
\includegraphics[decodearray={0 0.8 0 0.8 0 0.8}]{blue_square}
\includegraphics[decodearray={0 0.6 0 0.6 0 0.6}]{blue_square}
\includegraphics[decodearray={0 0.4 0 0.4 0 0.4}]{blue_square}
\includegraphics[decodearray={0 0.2 0 0.2 0 0.2}]{blue_square}
\includegraphics[decodearray={0 0 0 0 0 0}]{blue_square}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, and help once again.